# Firebase on call function htpps.oncall is not sending context information to security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

Firebase on call function(functions.https.onCall) is not sending the context parameter values to the security rules. Which means that if from UI we call an firebase on call function to update something to firestore db i need to do all security checks in that function and use admin sdk to update firestore db. I can not make use of firebase sdk and firestore security rules for authenticated updates.

```
export const registerOrganizationTest = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {   firebase.firestore().collection('Organizations').doc('counts').get()
await firebase.firestore().collection('Organizations').doc('counts').set(orgcounts, { merge: true })
        await firebase.firestore().collection('Organizations').
            doc((orgcounts.organizationCount).toString()).
            set(organization, { merge: true })
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", err);
    }
})
```

Firestore stops updates as security rules violated. But if same statements run from UI they pass as context parameter is available to security rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security rules don't apply to backend code.  When you invoke a Cloud Function or some other backend code that uses the Admin SDK or the other Cloud SDKs for backend components, all access from that code bypasses security rules completely.  Security rules only apply when Firestore is accessed directly from the mobile and web client SDKs (Android, iOS, Unity, etc).